# extracting tables using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all the tables from a html file as given below using BeautifulSoup and write it to csv.

Html looks like below:

```
        <h4>Site Name : Aria</h4>   
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th style="width: 25%"><strong>Dn Name:</strong></th>
                    <td style="width: 25%"><strong>Aria</strong></td>

                        <th style="width: 25%"><strong>WL:</strong></th>
                        <td style="width: 25%"><strong> Meters (m)</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>River Name:</strong></th>
                    <td><strong>Ben</strong></td>

                        <th><strong>DL:</strong></th>
                        <td><strong> Meters (m)</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Basin Name:</strong></th>
                    <td><strong>GAN<strong></strong></strong></td>

                    <th><strong>HFL:</strong></th>
                    <td><strong>49.4 Meters (m)<strong></strong></strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Div Name:</strong></th>

                    <td><a target="_blank" href="http://imd.gov.in/ onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target, &#39;width=1000, height=600, toolbar=no, resizable=no&#39;); return false;">LGD-I</a></td>

                    <th><strong>HFL date:</strong></th>
                    <td>14-08-2017</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><strong>PRESENT WL</strong></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>                            

                    <td class="" style="width:33%; height:18px;">Date: 17-07-2018 12:00</td>
                    <td class="" style="width:33%;">Value: 45.43 Meters (m)</td>
                    <td class="" style="width:33%;">Trend: Steady</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><strong>CUMULATIVE DAILY RF</strong></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                        <td style="width:33%; height:18px;">Date: 17-07-2018 08:30</td>
                        <td style="width:33%;">Value: 0.0 Milimiters (mm)</td>
                        <td style="width:33%;"></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody></table>                            
                <p>&nbsp;</p>                       



                            <table style="width: 100%">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center;"><strong>NO FORECAST</strong></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>




</div>
```

I amble to extract the text from all the three table but I am not able to write it in the desired format

My code

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
os.chdir(r'D:\shared')


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html5lib")

tables = soup.find_all("tr")
test =[]
for table in tables:
    test.append(table.get_text())

filename = 'Water'+'-'+str(date)+'.csv'
out = open(filename, mode='ab')
writer = csv.writer(out)
writer.writerow(data)
out.close()
```

In output csv first table is being written in 1st column 2nd table is being written in second table and third table is written in 3rd column.

I want data in the following format:

```
Site Name:  Aria
Dn Name:    Aria    
WL:         Meters (m)
River Name: Ben 
DL:         Meters (m)
Basin Name: GAN
HFL:        49.4 Meters (m)
Div Name:   LGD-I)
HFL date:   14-08-2017

PRESENT WL
Date:       17-07-2018 12:00    
Value:      45.43 Meters (m)    
Trend:      Steady
CUMULATIVE 
DAILY RF
Date:       17-07-2018 08:30    
Value:      0.0 Milimiters (mm) 
NO FORECAST
```

Comment: what's the structure of `data` - the vairable you are writing with csv writer?

Comment: Data is html as mentioned above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt to this problem:

```
data = """
        <h4>Site Name : Aria</h4>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th style="width: 25%"><strong>Dn Name:</strong></th>
                    <td style="width: 25%"><strong>Aria</strong></td>

                        <th style="width: 25%"><strong>WL:</strong></th>
                        <td style="width: 25%"><strong> Meters (m)</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>River Name:</strong></th>
                    <td><strong>Ben</strong></td>

                        <th><strong>DL:</strong></th>
                        <td><strong> Meters (m)</strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Basin Name:</strong></th>
                    <td><strong>GAN<strong></strong></strong></td>

                    <th><strong>HFL:</strong></th>
                    <td><strong>49.4 Meters (m)<strong></strong></strong></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Div Name:</strong></th>

                    <td><a target="_blank" href="http://imd.gov.in/ onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target, &#39;width=1000, height=600, toolbar=no, resizable=no&#39;); return false;">LGD-I</a></td>

                    <th><strong>HFL date:</strong></th>
                    <td>14-08-2017</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><strong>PRESENT WL</strong></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td class="" style="width:33%; height:18px;">Date: 17-07-2018 12:00</td>
                    <td class="" style="width:33%;">Value: 45.43 Meters (m)</td>
                    <td class="" style="width:33%;">Trend: Steady</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><strong>CUMULATIVE DAILY RF</strong></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                        <td style="width:33%; height:18px;">Date: 17-07-2018 08:30</td>
                        <td style="width:33%;">Value: 0.0 Milimiters (mm)</td>
                        <td style="width:33%;"></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>



                            <table style="width: 100%">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center;"><strong>NO FORECAST</strong></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
</div>"""

import os
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
# For Python 2.7 the next line should be "from itertools import izip_longest"
from itertools import zip_longest
import csv

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
# os.chdir(r'D:\shared')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

tables = []
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    current_table = []
    tables.append(current_table)
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        for (th, td) in zip_longest(row.find_all('th'), row.find_all('td')):
            s = ("%s %s" % (th.text.strip() if th else '', td.text.strip() if td else '')).strip()
            if s:
                current_table.append(s)

tables[0].insert(0, ': '.join(w.strip() for w in soup.find('h4').text.split(':')))

for table in tables:
    for i in table:
        print(i)

filename = 'CWC-Water'+'-'+str(date)+'.csv'
out = open(filename, mode='w')
writer = csv.writer(out)
for table in zip_longest(*tables):
    writer.writerow(table)
out.close()
```

Prints:

```
Site Name: Aria
Dn Name: Aria
WL: Meters (m)
River Name: Ben
DL: Meters (m)
Basin Name: GAN
HFL: 49.4 Meters (m)
Div Name: LGD-I
HFL date: 14-08-2017
PRESENT WL
Date: 17-07-2018 12:00
Value: 45.43 Meters (m)
Trend: Steady
CUMULATIVE DAILY RF
Date: 17-07-2018 08:30
Value: 0.0 Milimiters (mm)
NO FORECAST
```

And outputs .csv file with following format (3-columns from tables, screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Edit:
- correct picture

Comment: Thanks for the help...  I am using Python 2.7 and getting error `s = f"{th.text.strip() if th else ''} {td.text.strip() if td else ''}".strip ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax.`Also can we write second table just below the first one and third table below second as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @gi.rajan Edited my answer, should work with Python 2.7

Comment: Ok now it's working I have to use from `itertools import izip_longest` for Python 2.7. Your code is printing data in the correct format can we save tables in the same format??? I want all the data in a single column.

Comment: I have modified your code to get desired output                                               `for table in tables:
    writer.writerows(izip(table))
out.close()`